# How to calculate the periodic cyclic homology group of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, homotopy-theory

$\newcommand{\ur}{\mathrm{ur}}$Fix a prime number $p$. We let $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ denote the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and  $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}_p$ denote the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$.
How to calculate the periodic cyclic homology group $\text{HP}_*(\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/\mathbb{Z})$ and $\text{HP}_*(\overline{\mathbb{Z}}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)$?
How about  $\text{HP}_*(\overline{\mathbb{Z}_p^{\ur}}/\mathbb{Z}_p)$?, where $\overline{\mathbb{Z}_p^{\ur}}$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p^{\ur}}$ which is the maximal unramified extension of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$.

Comment: Let $A_\inf = W((\overline{\mathbf{Z}}/p)^\flat)$, and let $\theta$ be the surjection from $A_\inf$ to the $p$-completion of $\overline{\mathbf{Z}}$. I believe $\pi_\ast \mathrm{HP}(\overline{\mathbf{Z}}/\mathbf{Z})$ is isomorphic to the $2$-periodification of $A_\mathrm{crys}$, i.e., the $p$-completion of the PD-envelope of  $\ker(\theta)\subseteq A_\inf$. The proof is essentially the same as Proposition 9.9 of http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bhattb/math/padicddr.pdf. (I wrote the comment this way to emphasize the analogy to the linked article.)

Comment: Name of @skd's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427341/how-to-calculate-the-periodic-cyclic-homology-group-of-overline-mathbbz-m#comment1098952_427341):  [Bhatt - $p$-adic derived de Rham cohomology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.6560).

Comment: (Slight correction: replace $\mathbf{Z}$, etc. with $\mathbf{Z}_p$; and $\pi_\ast \mathrm{HP}(\overline{\mathbf{Z}_p}/\mathbf{Z}_p)$ is only $p$-completely isomorphic to the $2$-periodification of $A_\mathrm{crys}$.)

Comment: @skd An extra completion w.r.t. the PD-filtration seems necessary: periodic cyclic homology admits a filtration with associated graded being shifted *Hodge-completed* derived de Rham cohomology.

Comment: For the maximal unramified extension, it seems that the extension of rings of integers is ind-étale, thus the Hodge-completed derived de Rham cohomology is very simple.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, thanks @Z.M.